# Filter array and match at least one condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I'd like to solve the following problem: I would like to filter an array by certain conditions with Vue.js and lodash (or pure JavaScript).

## My objects

- I got a list of `Items`. Each item contains (optional) `categories`.
- The object `Car` can have a `category`.

#### Array of Objects `Items`

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Item 1",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "title": "category 4",
          "description": "",
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "title": "category 5",
          "description": "",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Item 2",
      "categories": []
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Item 3",
      "categories": []
    }
  ]
```

#### Object `Car`

```
{
  "category": {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "category 5",
    "description": ""
  },
  "title": "Test"
}
```

## My goal

I would like to only show those `Items`, which are passing at least **one** of these rules:

- The `Item` has at least one `category` that matches the `category` of the `Car`
- The `Item` has **no** `category` set

## My approach

I am using a `computed` value to filter `this.items`:

```
computed: {
        filteredItems: function () {
            let vm = this;
            return _.filter (this.items, function (item) {
                return _.includes (item.categories, vm.car.category );
            });
        }
    },
```

## Current result:

`filteredItems` is always empty.

Comment: You could compare using the ID only, assuming this is unique per category. The return value of your function would be something like `return !item.categories.length || _.includes(item.categories.map(category => category.id), vm.car.category.id);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to do one more level of checking on `categories` because you need to test against each item inside it. With regular javascript you can do that with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which will return true if any of the items match.

```js
let data = [{"id": 1,"title": "Item 1","categories": [{"id": 4,"title": "category 4","description": "",},{"id": 5,"title": "category 5","description": "",}]},{"id": 2,"title": "Item 2","categories": []},{"id": 3,"title": "Item 3","categories": []}]
let  car = {"category": {"id": 5,"title": "category 5","description": ""},"title": "Test"}

let filtered = data.filter(item => !item.categories || item.categories.length === 0 ||  item.categories.some(cat=> cat.id === car.category.id))
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `lodash` you'd need something like

```
result = _.filter(data, ({categories}) =>
    _.isEmpty(categories) ||
    _.some(categories, cat => cat.id === car.category.id))
```

If you'd like to compare the whole category objects, not just ids, then

```
_.filter(data, ({categories}) => 
    _.isEmpty(categories) || 
    _.some(categories, cat => _.isEqual(cat, car.category)
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there an elegant method to check, whether `car.category` is set at all? I would do it wrapping it to an `if` check like this: `if (typeof vm.car.category !== 'undefined'){...}`

Comment: @SPQRInc: in the second snippet, `isEqual` will take care of that. No need to check.