# Check array for at least one condition and not have it overridden by later checks

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

### Problem

A for loop is checking an array to see if it matches at least one condition. Later iterations in this for loop are seemingly overriding the original matches.

### Question

How do I check an array to see if it matches at least one condition, and not have later iterations of this check override (and thus turn false) the results?

### Goal

The attached code snippet should render the `<article>` elements that have *any* matches in their corresponding `currentItemTags` array with the `showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags` array. Because `showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags` contains `["digital", "2016"]`, that would mean the Australia and Mexico elements should show—as both of their `currentItemTags` contains a match to something in `showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags`

### Approach

The below code aims to do the following:

1. Loops through each `pageItem` (the three `<article>` element)
2. Prepares the `currentItemTags` array for the `pageItem`
3. Loops through the `showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags` array
4. Checks `currentItemTags` for matches with `showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags`
5. Applies a hide/show CSS class depending on whether there is a match or not, respectively

I suspect step 5 is where things go wrong. I have tried applying the [.some()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796095/2009441) and [.filter()](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-not-check-an-entire-array-for-a-condition-one-vs-all-9e6eb303acf9) methods unsuccessfully—unable to make these work in this context.

```js
// Set up
const pageItems = document.querySelectorAll("main article");

// Changing items in this array should show or hide page items
const showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags = [
  "digital",
  "2016"
];

for (let i = 0; i < pageItems.length; i++) {
  // Access each item
  const currentItem = pageItems[i];

  // Manually deconstruct this item's dataset into one array
  const currentItemTags = [];
  currentItemTags.push(
    currentItem.getAttribute("data-type"),
    currentItem.getAttribute("data-year"),
    currentItem.getAttribute("data-topic"),
    currentItem.getAttribute("data-country")
  );


  // Where I think the problem is:

  // Check this item's dataset array if it contains a matche with showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags
  for (let j = 0; j < showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags.length; j++) {
    
    if (currentItemTags.includes(showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags[j])) {
      // currentItemTags array contains a match with showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags
      // Show this item
      currentItem.classList.remove("hideItem");
      currentItem.classList.add("showItem");
    } else {
      // currentItemTags does not contain ANY match with showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags
      // Hide this item
      currentItem.classList.remove("showItem");
      currentItem.classList.add("hideItem");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Set up */
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

article {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Classes references in JS */
.showItem {
  display: auto;
  /* back to default */
}

.hideItem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article data-type="analog" data-year="2016" data-topic="food" data-country="australia">Analog, 2016, Food, Australia</article>
  <article data-type="digital" data-year="2017" data-topic="art" data-country="mexico">Digital, 2017, Art, Mexico</article>
  <article data-type="analog" data-year="2020" data-topic="music" data-country="poland">Analog, 2020, Music, Poland</article>
</main>
```

### Current result

Only the Australia `<article>` element shows. Mexico should show, too.

Comment: Break out of the loop once you detect that a condition has been matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simpliest way to get all data attributes in JS is  `Object.values(element.dataset)`

but if you have other unconcerned data attributes do
`listArray = [element.dataset.type, element.dataset.year, element.dataset.topic, element.dataset.country ]`

the way to verify if 2 array have some common elements  :
`if (arr1.some(key=>arr2.includes(key)))`

the complete code:

```js
const pageItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('main article')]
                    .map(el=>({el:el, keys:Object.values(el.dataset)}) );

function articleFiltering( showOnly )
  {
  pageItems.forEach(item=>
    {
    if (showOnly.some(key=>item.keys.includes(key))) 
      { item.el.classList.remove('hideItem') }
    else
      { item.el.classList.add('hideItem')    }
    }) 
  }

const showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags = [ 'digital', '2016' ]; 

articleFiltering( showOnlyItemsWithTheseTags )
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }
article {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
.hideItem {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<main>
  <article data-type="analog"  data-year="2016" data-topic="food"  data-country="australia" > Analog, 2016, Food, Australia </article>
  <article data-type="digital" data-year="2017" data-topic="art"   data-country="mexico"    > Digital, 2017, Art, Mexico    </article>
  <article data-type="analog"  data-year="2020" data-topic="music" data-country="poland"    > Analog, 2020, Music, Poland   </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I have another data attribute (not shown here on SO) which is an array itself, so I suppose I could follow your _if you have other unconcerned data attributes_ advice and use the spread operator. That being said, the `some()` function works as-is with that additional data attribute.

Comment: @Danny happy to have helped